# $line variable is not working inside the sed statement

Tags: unix, sed

i am trying to display the line number whenever the charcter count is less than 9. If it less than 9, then i want to add a tab at the end of the line.
However while doing that in the sed command i am not view $line in the output.

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
#set -x

while read line; do
  count=`echo $line|wc -m`
  if [ $count -lt 9 ]
  then
    sed -n '/$line/=' Length4.txt;
  fi
done < Length4.txt
```

Length.txt

```
ABCD
DEFG
HFIJ
KLMN
```

Comment: Shell is a an environment from which to call tools. The tool to parse arbitrary text files is awk. You are parsing a text file so just use awk and the resulting script will be briefer, clearer, and more robust. Post some more representative sample input (e.g. some lines with 9 or more chars) and the expected output given that input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need double quotes in shell for variable expansion:

```
sed -n "/$line/=" Length4.txt
```

Though if you describe your problem better we can help you cleanup some code.

Comment: Thank you. It works. However my requirement is little more complex. from(sed -n "/$line/=" Length4.txt) i will get line numbers. Here all lines will be shown. because all the lines character count is less than 9. So i want to change the values of those lines by adding one more tab at the end of those lines only.

Comment: Do you just want `1\t\n2\t\n3\t\n4\t\n` in output? Can you please show your expected file content after this loop.

Comment: it will be same as length.txt except the character count for line one to 4 should be character count of 4+8(tab)= 12. I am not able to add the contents as because you will not able to identify the difference. because tab will be there at the end of each line end.

Comment: You can put `\t` for tab and `\n` for new line and that will be helpful for understanding of visitors on this page.

Comment: inputfile
===========
GGGGGGGGGG
ABCD\t
DEFG\t
LLLLLLLLLL
HFIJ\t
NNNNNNNNNN
KLMN\t
ZZZZZZZZZZ

Output file
===========
GGGGGGGGGG
ABCD\t
DEFG\t
LLLLLLLLLL
HFIJ\t
NNNNNNNNNN
KLMN\t
ZZZZZZZZZZ

Comment: Your input and output files look same. Its better to provide this data in your question where it is far easier to read.

Comment: @user2642751 - it sounds from your comment `character count of 4+8(tab)= 12.` like you think a tab character counts as 8 characters. It doesn't. A tab character is one character.

Answer (score 0):

This whole thing could be solved a little easier with `awk`:

```
awk 'length($0) < 9 { print NR }' Length4.txt
```